# What is the reasoning for a deque to have a subscript operator?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, deque

I was talking to a friend today and he brought up how weird it is that deque  elements are able to be accessed by subscript operator when other "similar" DSs, like queue and stack are not. After all, doesn't deque just mean double-ended queue? Doesn't the fact that deque's can be randomly accessed ruin the very integrity of the deque data structure?

Also, for a performance standpoint, don't deque's just bring less to the table entirely with the subscript operator unless you're actually utilizing deque methods (the family of front and back functions)? I understand that the implementation behind deque's splits it up into chunks/blocks, and that it generally takes two operations to actually randomly access a element, whereas vectors are guaranteed to be in contiguous memory.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a vector as a queue too.  It just performs like crap. =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doesn't the fact that deque's can be randomly accessed ruin the very integrity of the deque data structure?

No. You are just hung up on the name for it. We do have a clear definition of a "queue" in mind, so this is a poor choice of words perhaps, but a data structure is not defined by its name.

A date structure is data (duh) with a specific set of associated operations. The standard library defined `deque` with a subscript operator. So that's the data structure. Great care was taken to make sure the various requirements on the operations don't conflict, so the integrity of `deque` as a data structure is held up quite nicely.

Comment: In other words, here `deque` is but a name for a vector with fast insertion/removal at the front.

Comment: @bipll: except it's not very similar to vector. First and foremost, `deque` does not allocate a contiguous block of memory like `vector` does.

Comment: bipll: deque cannot be implemented as a vector. every now and then the underlying memory of vector will be reallocated when capacity is reached. Yet in the C++ standard, if elements inserted via push_front/push_back _ONLY_, then a reference to an element in the middle of a deque is valid for all time. The only way this can be met is if deque is a array of pointers to pages of elements. The array can be reallocated and new pages added to the front and back without disturbing existing pages.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, for a performance standpoint, don't deque's just bring less to the table entirely with the subscript operator unless you're actually utilizing deque methods (the family of front and back functions)? I understand that the implementation behind deque's splits it up into chunks/blocks, and that it generally takes two operations to actually randomly access a element, whereas vectors are guaranteed to be in contiguous memory.

deque compared to vector has another advantage. it is possible to run out of memory for a vector, if the contiguous memory is huge, more than the OS can allocate. Because deques are paged memory, a good implementation could make lower demands on an OS because the memory requirements are non-contiguous.